# Spring Batch Remote Partitioning : Worker partitions not running in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-cloud-task

I have a Spring Batch remote partitioning application which is generating the partition's ok and the partitions functionally are working. 
However, at the moment the partition's are running sequentially and not in parallel. I am running the job/tasks/partitions in spring cloud data flow.
I have split my master and worker functionality into separate classes/packages which have separate profiles.
My master profile class code(partial) is :

```
public class PartitionMaster {
....
// Configure Remote Job
    @Bean
    public Job jobRemotePartitioning() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory
                .get("jobRemotePartitioning")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(paymentRaiseMasterStep())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
....
   @Bean
    public Step paymentRaiseMasterStep() {
        CustomPartitioner customPartitioner = new CustomPartitioner(datasource, propertiesConfig.getTimeTravelDate(), propertiesConfig.getLeadTime());
        return this.masterStepBuilderFactory
                .get("paymentRaiseMasterStep")
                .partitioner("paymentRaiseWorkerStep", customPartitioner)
                .gridSize(propertiesConfig.getGrid())
                .outputChannel(masterPaymentRaiseRequests())
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }
....
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("paymentRaiseWorkerStep");
    }
....
}
```

My worker profile class code(partial) is :

```
public class PartitionWorker {
....
    @Bean
    public Step paymentRaiseWorkerStep() {
        return this.workerStepBuilderFactory
                .get("paymentRaiseWorkerStep")
                .inputChannel(consumePaymentRaiseMasterRequests())
                .tasklet(taskletProcessing(null, null))
                .build();
    }
....
}
```

Any expert Spring Batch remote partitioning advice would be greatly appreciated.
When I have 2 partitions running in spring cloud data flow :

[Step partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sImKU.png)
[Full Job Completed Step Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYSyQ.png)

If I run 2 workers, 1 worker processes both partitions sequentially. The other worker does not process any partitions.

I am using scdf to run the master and workers as tasks :

[scdf tasks(1 master 2 workers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liB0E.png)

Comment: How many workers do you have?  Your configuration will only support one step per worker at a time so if you only have one worker, the partitions will be executed serially.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the reply. If I have 2 step partitions, as per the diagram I have added to the issue above. I run 2 workers using profile "partitionworker" and both start but the first worker processes both step partitions.

Comment: Define a worker?  These are external processes, correct or are they internal to the same JVM?

Comment: My workers are being run as scdf tasks as shown in the edits above, which I would imagine that scdf would be running within the same JVM.

Comment: SCDF runs them as separate JVMs.  What platform are you running these on?  We'd need to see the logs.  Nothing here is obviously wrong.

Comment: Hi Michael - thanks for the help. I have uploaded the logs and source to github https://github.com/karwidmer/stackoverflow.git

Comment: Thanks for the help. This has now been resolved.